# How would you process a list with 1 million objects in aws lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table in DynamoDB with 1 million rows.

I need to run a process on the 1 million rows.

The table would look like so:

```
Date,   Type,  Quantity, value
Jan23,    M,   10,       0.4
Jan24,    F,    5,       0.6
Jan26,    M,    6,       0.8
```

The process would go as follows:

- Take all records of F and M and sort them individually into two lists by date.

List 1:

```
Jan23, M , 10, 0.4
jan26, M, 6, 0.8
```

List2:

```
Jan24, F, 5,0.6
```

- Now for each row in List2 I need to find the first available row in List 1 and process it.

So (10*0.4-0.6*5) = 1 <- Log this value

- Now since I took away 5 from jan23 row, it only has 5 as quantity remaining.

It's a simple process, however, can this be done in Lambda with 1 million records? I would somehow need the Lambda to have a hold of all 1 million records, as the list cannot be split due to having to know the quantity of each row.

The data is stored in DynamoDB and not S3 because some rows need to be edited with ease from a web app. I can and will implement a way to store it on S3 if that is needed for this solution.

I've been looking for a parallel implementation, but for that I would need to know where to split each list beforehand.

Comment: Is the combination of type plus date unique or, for example, are there multiple M records for the same date? What is the range of dates?

Comment: Yeah, there are multiple M records for the same day. The range of dates is from 2010 to current. @jarmod

Comment: Please post code to show an attempt to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are solving the problem with the wrong database. Dynamo is not to be used for analytical or statistical problem-solving.

DymanoDB is not meant to be used for huge data fetch at least as of now.

Solutions,

> DynamoDB -- Streams -- Lambda -- RDS

Do all the complex query with RDS.

If the data is going to grow huge, you can introduce Redshift as well.

> DynamoDB -- Streams  -- Lambda -- Firehose -- Redshift

Use Redshift tools and update the results to DymanoDB for transactional consumption.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Could I store the information in s3 and dynamo, then instead of rds use s3. Where it is stored as a csv file?

Comment: Your data is relational. You'll want to use a relational database, like RDS.